# Provided Beforehand - Single word

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

I am trying to find a good single-word for sentences requiring a word which conveys the meaning of "provided beforehand", "pre-given", "pre-provided", etc.

In order to simplify this, I'll provide two example sentences, each of which will have a blank over the missing word which I'm looking for:

> "Complete these sentences using the (             ) words: ... "
>
> "He told me that I have to write an essay using at least one of the (             )
> scientific terms in each paragraph."

Hope my question is clear enough. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think I would say, simply "provided".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Given** could be used on its own (in your sentence) because the **pre-** you suggest is superfluous. **Given** on its own implies that it has already been mentioned.

#### Supporting evidence

To support this with a source, take one of the definitions listed by [Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/given):

> Specified or stated.

They also provide some example sentences, one of them is:

> ‘His observations of the defenders dictates which play to use in a given situation.’

A more technical use can be found in *The Encyclopaedia Britannica : a dictionary of arts, sciences, literature and general information*, [on page 117](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-lhBAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA117&dq=%22of+the+given+terms%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig_anF4PfaAhXCZFAKHY4xD1IQ6AEITzAH#v=onepage&q=%22of%20the%20given%20terms%22&f=false) (emphasis is mine):

> To interpolate a series is to interpose among its terms others which shall be subject to the same law, or which shall be formed in the same manner as the original terms of the series; or, in other words, it is to find the value of one or more terms by means of others which are given, and which may be either at equal or unequal intervals from one another, the places **of the given terms** as well as of those sought being supposed known.

Attribution:

[1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/given) "Given | Definition of given in English by Oxford Dictionaries." Oxford Dictionaries | English. Accessed May 09, 2018. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/given.

[2](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-lhBAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA117&dq=%22of+the+given+terms%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig_anF4PfaAhXCZFAKHY4xD1IQ6AEITzAH#v=onepage&q=%22of%20the%20given%20terms%22&f=false) Stewart, Dugald, and Macvey Napier. Encyclopaedia Britannica, Or, Dictionary of Arts, Sciences, and General Literature ...: Including the Late Supplement, a General Index and Numerous Engravings. Vol. 20. Edinburgh: A. & C. Black, 1842.

Answer (score 5):

***Aforementioned***, perhaps

(*previously mentioned, esp. in a text* OED)

Answer (score 2):

"He told me that I have to write an essay using at least one of the **provided** scientific terms in each paragraph."

provide  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/provide)

> 1. to make available; furnish: to provide employees with benefits.
> 2. to supply or equip: to provide the army with tanks.
> 3. to afford or yield.
> 4. to stipulate beforehand, as by a provision.

*Provided* is good all by itself.